# How can sort Antd table data by length, when the data contain a null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, tablesorter

I want to sort a table by the length of the data. But there are some null values coming.
This is my sorter function

```
 sorter: (a, b) => a.rechargeType.length - b.rechargeType.length
```

following error coming when there is a null value

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do that,

```
sorter: (a, b) => {
    if(a && a.rechargeType && a.rechargeType.length && b && b.rechargeType && b.rechargeType.length) {
        return a.rechargeType.length - b.rechargeType.length;
    } else if(a && a.rechargeType && a.rechargeType.length) {
        // That means be has null rechargeType, so a will come first.
        return -1;
    } else if(b && b.rechargeType && b.rechargeType.length) {
        // That means a has null rechargeType so b will come first.
        return 1;
    }

    // Both rechargeType has null value so there will be no order change.
    return 0;
}
```

This way null values will come last. For more reading about the return value of sort compare function you can read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).